# Insert Custom Post Type from Front End Form with Meta Data

Tags: php, wordpress

I can successfully create a WordPress custom post using a form. The issue I have is I can't get the post meta into the custom post type.

In my form processor file:

```
$custom1 = isset($_POST['custom1']) ? $_POST['custom1'] : '';
$custom2 = isset($_POST['custom2']) ? $_POST['custom2'] : '';
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

//Insert form data into post array
        $post_information = array(
            'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($title),
            'post_content' => $description,
            'post_type' => 'review-listing',
            'post_status' => 'draft'
        );
        wp_insert_post($post_information);
        if ($post_id) {
           // insert post meta
           add_post_meta($post_id, 'custom1', $custom1);
           add_post_meta($post_id, 'custom2', $custom12);
        }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Is ```$post_id``` defined anywhere? If you change the line above the if statement to ```$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information );``` does it work?

Comment: @Matt thanks for the comment, unfortunately it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the if statement evaluating to true?